# Dive into qemu source code to trace io requests

Tags: io, qemu

I searched a lot about qemu and read its documentation but could not find any explaining its I/O stack. Specifically, I want to know about how an I/O request is created and what path it travels to reach where.

For example, [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Storage_Stack_Diagram) is Linux I/O stack and [this good blog post](https://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2013/09/14/the-life-of-io-in-the-linux-kernel/) traced the path of an I/O request through the Linux kernel source code.

Can anyone give me the same information about qemu's I/O stack?